# Unattended ubuntu installation with Packer : error while selecting the language

Tags: 18.04, system-installation, language-support, preseed, vagrant

I was trying to use packer to setup a VM with ubuntu1804. VM is a virtualbox vagrant machine.

I followed the pressed file and other scripts from here: https://github.com/geerlingguy/packer-boxes/tree/master/ubuntu1804

But when trying to build the json with packer, it runs...but the unattended installation of ubuntu has a problem at the step where it says to choose the language, in the following screen.

[image]

It is shown in the UI that it doesn't selects the specified language 'English', but it first toggles between all the options available in the list and selects some another language instead (In my case it selected 'Galicia'). Then it shows a dialogue box which is in Galicia language. The English meaning of the message somewhat looks like this:
The translation of the installer into the chosen language is not complete.

```
The possibility of finding a message that is not translated into the chosen language and is very small, but cannot be completely discarded.

You want to continue the installation in the language of your choice?


Yes                No
```

I choose Yes, then a box shown as shown below and i choose English. After that, still installation didn't seems to be perfect.
[image]

I am using the following versions:

**Packer** 1.5.5

**Vagrant** 2.2.7

**VirtualBox** 6.1.4

**Ubuntu ISO**: http://cdimage.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/releases/bionic/release/ubuntu-18.04.4-server-amd64.iso

Can someone help me to solve this issue?

Comment: Cross-posted: https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/578177/packer-ubuntu-unattended-installation-error-while-selecting-the-language

Comment: Okay, i will delete the other one.